# How can I have assets compiled into image, stylesheet, and javascript directories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

The asset pipeline puts everything into the same directory. Images, stylesheets, and javascripts all go into /public/assets (although subdirectories are respected).

Is there a way to have them copied into /public/assets/images, public/assets/stylesheets, and public/assets/javascripts?

Adding to the confusion is this line in the rails guide:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets

> In regular views you can access images in the public/assets/images directory like this:

But rails doesn't use or make a public/assets/images directory.

Comment: Have you tried to [precompiling the assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets)? 

`RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails assets:precompile`

The files within the `app/assets` then should appear in public assets directory, with their `md5hash` fingerprint suffixed to their filenames to help with expiring/replacing downloaded assets within the client's browser, should they change in the future.

Comment: @sonna:  If you're confident about this, you should post a proper answer to the question.

Comment: I am not sure if they want to change the output directories; so that its `public/images/example.png` instead of `public/example.png`; or if they are just trying to precompile assets in development, since the `public/assets/images` will not exist unless the asset was multiple subdirectories like `app/assets/images/images/example.png` or `app/assets/all/images/example.png` to resolve Sprockets `logical_path` within Rails.

Comment: @sonna I want to change the directories that the assets are compiled into in production, so that images, fonts, stylesheets, and javascripts are each in subdirectories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution #1:

Create a new subdirectory within the `app/assets/` like `all` and move the
current asset directories into that the new folder; e.g.

```
mkdir -p app/assets/all
mv app/assets/{javascripts,images,stylesheets} app/assets/all/
```

Then when precompiling assets with `RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile`
it should create those `javascripts`, `images` and `stylesheets` directories
underneath the `public/assets` directory;

```
public/assets/javascripts
public/assets/images
public/assets/stylesheets
```

### Solution #2:

You can create a new directory somewhere else in your project; like `assets`,
instead of `app/assets`; and add that the new directory to the current Rails
asset paths configuration within the `assets.rb` initializer

```
# app/config/initializers/assets.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.application.root.join("assets")
```

Then precompiling assets should have the same effect as **Solution #1**.

### Solution #3

So, as part of the Sprocket-Rails Engine it preloads the `app/assets`
subdirectories with this following block of code:

```
# ~/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:54
module Rails
  # [...]

  class Engine < Railtie
    # Skip defining append_assets_path on Rails <= 4.2
    unless initializers.find { |init| init.name == :append_assets_path }
      initializer :append_assets_path, :group => :all do |app|
        app.config.assets.paths.unshift(*paths["vendor/assets"].existent_directories)
        app.config.assets.paths.unshift(*paths["lib/assets"].existent_directories)
        app.config.assets.paths.unshift(*paths["app/assets"].existent_directories)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The line of interest is the

```
app.config.assets.paths.unshift(*paths["app/assets"].existent_directories)
```

It call to `existent_directories` off the `*paths["app/assets"]` is returning
all the subdirectories within the assets folder, hence why there are no
subdirectories in the `public/assets` folder when Sprocket computes its digested
assets.

In order to add those sub-directories back in, we have to modify the current
Rails configured environment for Sprockets; i.e.
`Rails.application.config.configure`. However, the `Sprockets::Paths` that is
included in the `Sprockets::Configuration` that
`Rails.application.config.configure` yields to does not allow public access to
its internal `@paths` variable, nor does it have an method to remove paths like
it does to add paths via its `append_paths`. Instead we have to duplicate the
current paths already included by the above Railtie initializer block, remove
the old `"app/assets"` subdirectories paths that we do not want, add in just the
`"app/assets"` directory we do want and then append them back into the configured
Sprockets environment; which looks something like this in a Rails initializer:

```
# app/config/initializers/assets.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.configure do |env|
  old_paths = env.paths.dup
  new_paths = old_paths - Rails.application.paths["app/assets"].existent_directories
  new_paths << Rails.application.root.join("app", "assets")

  env.clear_paths
  new_paths.each { |path| env.append_path(path) }
end
```

### Closing Comments

Using any of these solution should also mean that you will need to specify the subdirectory in all your
`asset_path` method calls within your view templates in order to find the
compiled asset; e.g.

```
<%= asset_path "images/example.png" %>
<%= asset_path "javascripts/application.js" %>
<%= asset_path "stylesheets/application.css" %>

/assets/images/example-ca63e56ac855bdfb187479a35a7476cd65c539727f84fea19e1ad258cf3d23f5.png
/assets/javascripts/application-a4f3e75c7f7aa6d6cbc2ebcbb436b12aca442553219883805baebdd2eecd5471.js
/assets/stylesheets/application-539757f75200b6ea43399bf5e25cbc2819c1e6a610f94d5c9beaf91fec89384e.css
```

I hope one these solutions help.